# Lua & SQL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, lua

I'm trying both of these ways to run a SQL query with Lua using the GMod mysqloo library.
Each query is complaining about the line with the EXISTS() having an SQL syntax error.

```lua
local SQL6 = [[INSERT INTO accounts(UniqueID,Money)
VALUES(]]..UniqueID..[[,]]..StartingCash..[[)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM accounts WHERE UniqueID=]]..UniqueID..[[)]]
local SQL7 = [[IF Not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE UniqueID=']]..UniqueID..[[')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO accounts(UniqueID,Money)
VALUES(]]..UniqueID..[[,]]..StartingCash..[[)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE UniqueID=]]..UniqueID..[[
END]]
```

Comment: Your SQL may be vulnerable to injection; see http://bobby-tables.com/about.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know SQL but it seems that:

- you need quotes around `UniqueID` in line 3 and 11, as in line 4.
- you probably need a space or newline before the last `END`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, already tried quotes and using ; at the end of the insert and select lines